# Changing already installed hard disk to other system results trouble?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, exchange

I have two good working systems. I just want to exchange the total files between these system.(I just wanna use the other system with good configuration with my files and environment). So i just exchanged the hard disk alone. But it results some error and windows open their auto repair wizard. That wizard also failed to repair. Is there any solution to change the hard disk with out reinstalling the Operating system?

This is what happening while i exchanging hard disks:

after exchange of hard disk, system ask me two options as "windows 7 (startup normally)" and "windows 7 (repair wizard). When we choose repair wizard. It checking system for errors and give result as "windows can not able to detect the problem" When we choose startup normally it gets restarts

My two system's configuration:

1) Intel dual core 2.8 ghz with 2 gb ram 
2) Intel pentium 2.60 ghz with 4 gb ram.

I just want to transfer from 1st system to 2nd system.

Comment: This is not a very good problem description. What is "some error"? And what "auto repair wizard" are you talking about? Most likely, the issue is an mismatch AHCI/IDE/RAID setting in the BIOS. If the modes don't match, the configuration has to be fixed *before* the hard drive changes systems.

Comment: after exchange of hard disk, system ask me two options as "windows 7 (startup normally)" and "windows 7 (repair wizard). When we choose repair wizard. It checking system for errors and give result as "windows can not able to detect the problem".

Comment: So what happens if you choose "startup normally"?

Comment: It restarts automatically

Comment: Have you tried starting up in safe mode? press F8 when starting up

Comment: What's the last thing you see before it restarts?

Comment: @JesperJensen: Sorry i won't tried it. Now i can't becoz i revert to the hard disk to the same system.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It just loading the windows animation, and restarted even that animation get end.

Comment: Don't understand, why can't you start in safe mode? It is probably rebooting because of driver issues, that why I wanted you to start in safe mode.

Comment: The problem you likely have is that your trying to boot Windows on different hardware thus its a driver problem.  While its possible to do this, its a lengthy process, and you need to be sure to change the Windows license before you connect to the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do this if you can get things back and working. So first, you would have to get your drive to work again on the original computer.

Then,  you have to prepare your OS by removing and disassociating all your hardware from the OS through the device manager and add remove programs.  That is, uninstall and remove all your non-onboard devices and remove the physical devices themselves; video cards, network cards, etc.  Then, you have do the same for all the things you cannot remove, most of these will only be in the device manager.  This article gives a good idea of how to do this. http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2007/09/how-to-install-a-new-motherboard-without-reinstalling-windows/

Finally, put the drive in a new computer and let it start and install new drivers.  Then, get all your disks and driver files and install like a new computer.

We have replaced a motherboard, cpu, and ram without replacing the hard drive.  You effectively are doing the same thing.  It can work.  You just have to prep properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain files that are created when you install Windows, as well as some other programs, that look at hardware identifiers - such as the manufacturer's id for the motherboard, CPU, Network card, and hard-drive controler. These are not the same as the part number, and are unique to every piece - even if the two pieces were created at the same time and are the same type.

They do this to make sure you don't just duplicate the drive and stick it into a new computer - and bypass copy protection. They usually will allow you to swap out one or two pieces every so often, but moving the hard-drive to a new computer is usually too much for them.

If you are swapping hardware completely like that, you usually need to do a full installation on the new PC and run a transfer program copying the user data from the old PC. Microsoft usually has these availible for free download. Often you will still need to reinstall applications as well.